# Absolute Positioning 100% Height Scroll Overflow Issue

Tags: html, css, css-position

Website... http://dev.rapweb.co.uk/londonplace/research.htm

Problem... When the browsers height is low enough to cause a vertical scroll bar, scrolling down just shows white space and the lower part of text in the red panel, isn't being displayed.

Solutions tried... Overflow Auto on the red panel causes an in page scroll bar. I'm assuming that's due to the absolute positioning.

Other ideas... I realise due to the background being set to cover and bottom aligned, it might not be possible to achieve what I originally planned, so I looked into having the text scroll behind the header, but that created issues when the browsers width was low enough to cause a horizontal scroll bar, because the text could then scroll outside the red panel and grey area, as it was no longer contained within them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the text is too large? Allow page scrolling?

Comment: Yes, ideally I would like the page to scroll down and the red and grey panel to continue, allowing additonal text to be displayed.
I'm not sure how this will work with the bottom aligned background image though.

Comment: Maybe the background image can just stay in place when scrolled?

Comment: That sounds like it could work well. Finding a way of expanding the red strip and grey content area to contain additional content is what I would like to try and achieve 1st.

Answer (score 0):

This makes the strip continue down and extends the image down.

Add this:

```
/* These 2 made the red strip not behave funny with <p> margins */

#redStripContent p:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

#redStripContent p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}

/* This extends the size of red strip */

#redStrip {
    position: relative; /* was absolute */
}
```

Remove this:

```
/* This removes the fixed bottom on main image area */

#mainImageArea {
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

As for your other page problems you mentioned in the comments, I suggest you play around with combinations of min-height:100% and negative margins. Try adding this for example:

```
#mainImageArea {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-top: -110px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply... That seemed to work great, but causes the image on my home page to not fill the screen.
http://dev.rapweb.co.uk/londonplace/index.htm
This would also be the case on the research page if the resolution was high enough to display all the content at once.

Comment: You may need to use JavaScript to accomplish this unfortunately. You can have a play with `min-height`, and negative margins but then you will cut the top of the image off.

Comment: I don't mind the top of the image being cut off, as the top goes behind the header when the browser is stretched wide anyway, but I'll look into Javascript as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Added a deeper explanation to answer of the min-height idea.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried that, but it caused some other knock on effects. I'll try some other options and see how I get on.

Comment: It's a pretty tricky layout really. You can also try having the background on some other element and position is as fixed and set it's z-index low.

Comment: I've gone for fixed color panels...
http://dev.rapweb.co.uk/londonplace/research.htm
I need to look into stopping the user scrolling left to right when the browser width is reduced. Not very mobile friendly though.

Comment: Mobile is normally easy to handle, just stack everything on top of each other.